# how to make a post with axios using node js as local server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http, axios

Hello everyone I have the following error in my post and I have no idea where the problem is coming from. I'm a beginner in node is and I'll give you my node JS server below
Server.js

```
const http = require('http');

class InMemoryDatabase {
    constructor() {
      this.data = [];
    }
  
    // Ajoute un objet à la base de données
    add(object) {
      this.data.push(object);
    }
  
    // Met à jour un objet dans la base de données
    update(id, object) {
      const index = this.findIndexById(id);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.data[index] = Object.assign(this.data[index], object);
      }
    }
  
    // Supprime un objet de la base de données
    delete(id) {
      const index = this.findIndexById(id);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.data.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  
    // Récupère tous les objets dans la base de données
    getAll() {
      return this.data;
    }
  
    // Récupère un objet de la base de données par son ID
    getById(id) {
      const index = this.findIndexById(id);
      if (index !== -1) {
        return this.data[index];
      }
    }
  
    // Recherche tous les objets dans la base de données qui correspondent à un filtre
    search(filter) {
      return this.data.filter(object => {
        for (const key in filter) {
          if (filter[key] !== object[key]) {
            return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
      });
    }
  
    // Trouve l'index d'un objet dans la base de données par son ID
    findIndexById(id) {
      return this.data.findIndex(object => object.id === id);
    }
  }

// Crée une instance de la base de données
const db = new InMemoryDatabase();

// Crée le serveur web
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  
  
    if (req.method === 'GET' && req.url === '/') {
      // Retourne tous les objets dans la base de données en format JSON
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      // add cors headers
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
      res.write(JSON.stringify(db.getAll()));
      res.end();
    } else if (req.method === 'GET' && req.url.startsWith('/object/')) {
      // Récupère un objet par son ID en format JSON
      const id = parseInt(req.url.split('/')[2]);
      const object = db.getById(id);
      if (object) {
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
        res.write(JSON.stringify(object));
      } else {
        res.statusCode = 404;
      }
      res.end();
    } else if (req.method === 'POST' && req.url === '/') {
      // Ajoute un nouvel objet à la base de données
      let data = '';
      req.on('data', chunk => {
        data += chunk;
      });
      req.on('end', () => {
        try {
          const object = JSON.parse(data);
          const id = db.add(object);
          res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
          res.setHeader('Location', `/object/${id}`);
          res.statusCode = 201;
          res.write(JSON.stringify({ id }));
        } catch (err) {
          res.statusCode = 400;
        }
        res.end();
      });
    } else {
      res.statusCode = 404;
      res.end();
    }
  });

// Lance le serveur web sur le port 8080
server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Serveur web lancé sur le port 8080');
});
```

Here is my client made in react JS I use the get and post methods here is my app.js file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Table, Button, Modal, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: ''
  });

  useEffect(() => {
  
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      setData(response.data);
    })
  }, []);

  const handleFormChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
      ...prevFormData,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };


  const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080", {
        name: "melvin",
        email: "test",
        phone: "test",
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    setShowModal(false);
  };

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    axios.delete(`/api/data/${id}`).then(() => {
      setData(data.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((item) => (
            <tr key={item.id}>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.email}</td>
              <td>{item.phone}</td>
              <td>
                <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => handleDelete(item.id)}>
                  Delete
                </Button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>
        Add Item
      </Button>
      <Modal show={showModal} onHide={() => setShowModal(false)}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Add Item</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
            <Form.Group controlId="name">
              <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Enter name"
                value={formData.name}
                onChange={handleFormChange}
                required
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId="email">
              <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Enter email"
                value={formData.email}
                onChange={handleFormChange}
                required
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group controlId="phone">
              <Form.Label>Phone</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                name="phone"
                placeholder="Enter phone number"
                value={formData.phone}
                onChange={handleFormChange}
                required
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
              Add
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here is the following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vcgo.png)

Comment: in your error, it said that you were requested to port `3000`, not to `8080`

Comment: To ensure your computer is allowing that port to be opened, are you able to access the end point with a browser (since it's a get req.)?

Answer (score -1):

use express.js to created server on node.js

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/express